# stringify an {} with X number object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem in the piece of code below. the goal is to create a JSON string.

The problem :obj content only the last value of the loop. (seem's legit when i read my code , but i can't find the solution). Is there an attribut on obj I shoud use? Otherwise, it works.

The result should look like :

```
{
"name": "foo",
"value": 0,
"coord": [
    {
        "lat": 30,
        "lng": 10
    }//,//currently i haven't other information from here.
    {
        "lat": 40,
        "lng": 0
    },
    {
        "lat": 20,
        "lng": 12
    }//to here
]
}
```

Here is the code :

```
var value = Zones[zob].value;
var tmp = Zones[zob].zone.getPath().getArray();
var coord = {};
var obj = {};

for(i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    coord['lat'] = tmp[i].lat();
    coord['lng'] = tmp[i].lng();
    obj = [coord]; //problem may come from here
}

var contact = new Object();
contact.name = zob;
contact.value = value;

contact.coord = [obj]; // or from here
var jsonresult = JSON.stringify(contact);

console.log(jsonresult);
```

Comment: you'ee overwriting coord and obj at every for-loop

Comment: Why are you defining OBJ as an OBJ, but then redefining it every loop as an array with value of COORD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an array and push your coordinates, as follows:

```
var value = Zones[zob].value;
var tmp = Zones[zob].zone.getPath().getArray();

var obj = []; // Created and array here

for(i=0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
    obj.push({
        lat: tmp[i].lat(),
        lng: tmp[i].lng()
    }); // Push an object
}

var contact = new Object();
contact.name = zob;
contact.value = value;

contact.coord = obj; // just assign the value
var jsonresult = JSON.stringify(contact);

console.log(jsonresult);
```